# Legend not showing up with manually defined colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing a map route with ggplot2. This is the code:

```
colombia_map <- ggplot(data = colombia, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = 'white', color = 'black', size = 1) + 
  coord_quickmap() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank())

colombia_map1 <- colombia_map +
  geom_point(data = nombres[2:3],
             aes(x = lon, y = lat),
             colour = "Black",
             size = 2, inherit.aes = F) +
    geom_curve(data = avianca,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Avianca"),
             col = "red",
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2, inherit.aes = F) +
  geom_curve(data = latam,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Latam"),
             col = "darkblue",
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2, inherit.aes = F) +
  geom_curve(data = easy,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Easy Fly"),
             col = "darkorange",
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2, inherit.aes = F, show.legend = T) +
  geom_curve(data = viva,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Viva Air"),
             col = "gold",
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2, inherit.aes = F, show.legend = T) +
  geom_curve(data = satena,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Satena"),
             col = "olivedrab",
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2, inherit.aes = F, show.legend = T) +
  geom_curve(data = wingo,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Wingo"),
             col = "purple",
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2, inherit.aes = F, show.legend = T) +
  geom_text_repel(data = nombres,
                  aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = Origen),
                  colour = "black",
                  size = 3.5, inherit.aes = F) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Operadores",
                     breaks = c("Avianca", "Latam", "Viva Air", "Easy Fly", "Satena", "Wingo"),
                     values = c("Avianca" = "red", "Latam" = "darkblue", "Viva Air" = "gold",
                                "Easy Fly" = "darkorange", "Satena" = "olivedrab", 
                                "wingo" = "purple")) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))
```

and this is the output:

[image: Route map of colombian airlines]

The problem is that I'm trying everything and I don't get why the legend doesn't appear in the plot. I'm trying with the aesthetic in the general mapping and the aesthetic in each geom_curve but nothing works!

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: You probably want to put the data into long format. Could you include a subset of your data in the question to make your question reproducible? Have a look at [mre]

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to replicate without your data, but here's a toy example doing something like what you are trying to do.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = psavert, colour = "PSAVERT")) +
  geom_line(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = uempmed, colour = "UEMPMED")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("PSAVERT"="blue","UEMPMED"="red"))
```

[image]

You have to put the colour value inside the `aes(...)`, but you can define the label inside there explicitly and it will map directly to the legend. You can then define your colours using `scale_colour_manual(values = c(....)`. But in your case you are overriding the `aes(..)` call with your explicit colour call, as in:

```
geom_curve(data = latam,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Latam"),
             col = "darkblue",
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2, inherit.aes = F)
```

So with that in mind, you could rewrite your code in a more simple way.

```
colombia_map <- ggplot(data = colombia, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = 'white', color = 'black', size = 1) + 
  coord_quickmap() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank())

colombia_map1 <- colombia_map +
  geom_point(data = nombres[2:3],
             aes(x = lon, y = lat),
             colour = "Black",
             size = 2, inherit.aes = F) +
    geom_curve(data = avianca,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Avianca"),
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2) +
  geom_curve(data = latam,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Latam"),
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2) +
  geom_curve(data = easy,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Easy Fly"),
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2) +
  geom_curve(data = viva,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Viva Air"),
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2) +
  geom_curve(data = satena,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Satena"),
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2) +
  geom_curve(data = wingo,
             aes(x = flon, y = flat, xend = tlon, yend = tlat, color = "Wingo"),
             size = 0.5,
             curvature = 0.2) +
  geom_text_repel(data = nombres,
                  aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = Origen),
                  colour = "black",
                  size = 3.5, inherit.aes = F) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Operadores",
                     values = c("Avianca" = "red", "Latam" = "darkblue", "Viva Air" = "gold",
                                "Easy Fly" = "darkorange", "Satena" = "olivedrab", 
                                "wingo" = "purple")) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))
```

That *should* work, but without a fully replicable example, hard to guarantee it. In the future, please share your data structure using `dput()`.

Comment: Yeah this works!! Thank you so much and I'll consider your suggestion about share the data next time.

Comment: If this works, please vote and accept the answer so this can be viewed as a reference for anyone else with the same problem down the line.